# Assign values to attributes after html enumerate

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for a way to assign attributes to a class object after executing `enumerate` on `html string`. Basically, this is what I have:

```
for j, td in enumerate(tr.select('td')):
   print(j, td.text)
```

This outputs:

```
0 UNITY
1 Unity Foods Limited
2 13.29
3 13.82
4  0.53
5  3.99%
6 0.12%
7 1.81
8 12,472,000
9 163
10 7,519
```

I want to assign these values to all the params in this following class:

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self,
                 symbol,
                 name,
                 ldcp,
                 current,
                 change,
                 change_percent,
                 index_wt,
                 index_point,
                 volume,
                 free_float,
                 market_cap):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.name = name
        self.ldcp = ldcp
        self.current = current
        self.change = change
        self.change_percent = change_percent
        self.index_wt = index_wt
        self.index_point = index_point
        self.volume = volume
        self.free_float = free_float
        self.market_cap = market_cap
```

Is there any `"pythonic"` way to address this problem?

Comment: assuming that your `tr.select` returns the exact number of params for your product class you could just do something like `my_product = Product(*[param.text for param in tr.select('td')])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collect the values into a list and pass them using argument unpacking:

```
attributes = [td.text for td in tr.select('td')]
product = Product(*attributes)
```

Note that this only works if the HTML contains the attributes in the order the are listed in the definition of `Product.__init__()`

You can apply filtering in the list comprehension if you want to ignore certain elements, e.g.:

```
attributes = [td.text for td in tr.select('td') if td.text != '']
product = Product(*attributes)
```

Comment: the first element looks like is empty in the `array`, the rest looks fine with the exact number of arguments. Is there a way to ignore `[]` from `attributes array`?

Comment: I've extended my answer

Comment: This does not create a `dictionary of objects`, correct? I want to be able to insert `products` which is an array of `product` into a `collection`. In this case I get the error `TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping`.

Comment: Turns out I had to insert the objects using the `__dict__` reference into the list. It works as expected after that.